# Handle Odata /entityset/key/navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

We have a project based on the DynamicEdmModelCreation project from ODataSamples-master odata examples.

We have set a Routing Convention that handle all request to this specific controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public EdmEntityObjectCollection Get()
{
...
}
[EnableQuery]
public IEdmEntityObject Get(string key)
{
...
}
```

We try for example

/odata/Hotels -> OK!

/odata/Hotels(1) -> Ok!

/odata/Hotels(1)/Room -> Response:

> No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation'.

Debuging we see that the route convention handle well the request and redirect it to our controller but no method is executed. The Routing Convention is:

```
public class MatchRoutingConventionService : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public string SelectAction(
        ODataPath odataPath,
        HttpControllerContext controllerContext,
        ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return (odataPath.Segments.FirstOrDefault() is EntitySetPathSegment) ? "HamdleAll" : null;
    }
}
```

We think the problem may be in WebApi chossing the correct method that will handle the request because since we are using the generic signature *IEdmEntityObject Get(string key)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, there're only two methods named `Get(), Get(string key)`. The result is:

1. `/odata/Hotels` is ok because the request can route to `Get()` method by convention.
2. `/odata/Hotels(1)` is ok because the request can route to `Get(string key)` by convention.

**However**, you doesn't create other methods to response other requests, such as for the request example:

`/odata/Hotels(1)/Room`

Owing that there's no methods responding to `~/entityset/key/navigation`, Web API OData can't find a method in your controller, so it throws the above error message.

#### My try:

- I create a simple method in https://github.com/xuzhg/ODataSamples/commit/289658ab5d7bb50c6270400946990c27809d44bc
- Besides, I also create the **general** navigation property access route in `SelectAction` the `MatchAllRoutingConvention`. See the commit: 
  https://github.com/xuzhg/ODataSamples/commit/200c4abd346f14ad258df2b36e8687f8ab7d85e7

You can modify it to meet your requirement. Hope it can help you.

Thanks.

Sam