# Handle OData functions parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

Based on the DynamicEdmModelCreation project from ODataSamples-master odata examples and following the help received in the question 
[Handle Odata /entityset/key/navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819648/handle-odata-entityset-key-navigation)
We now need to expose dynamic Actions and Funcions with parameters. To support unbound function we made in the GetModel Function the following:

```
var GetSum = new EdmFunction("ns", "GetSum",
            new EdmPrimitiveTypeReference(EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetPrimitiveType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double), false), 
            false, null, true);
GetSum.AddParameter("param1", 
            new EdmPrimitiveTypeReference(EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetPrimitiveType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double), 
            false));
GetSum.AddParameter("param2", 
            new EdmPrimitiveTypeReference(EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetPrimitiveType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Double), 
            false));

model.AddElement(GetSum);
container.AddFunctionImport(GetSum);
```

and in the SelectAction method we put:

```
if (odataPath.Segments.Count > 0 && 
            odataPath.Segments.Last() is UnboundFunctionPathSegment && 
            odataPath.Segments.Last().ToString().Contains("GetSum"))
            return "ExecuteFunction";
```

Finally the controller has

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ExecuteFunction(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    ...
}
```

Now testing the service:

```
http://localhost:2900/odata/GetSum(param1=1,param2=2)
```

Everything works fine except for the parameters, they always enter as null. Is there anything that we are missing to support the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring a function but in controller it's a action, according to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support, it should be

```
[HttpGet]
public string ExecuteFunction(double p1, double p2)
{
   ...
}
```

in controller

Comment: The problem is that in my code the odata model, actions and functions are dynamic like the DynamicEdmModelCreation project so I cannot set the signature specific to that odata function.